# Rails 3 ActiveRecord query: find the number of this product that have been ordered by this user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I have an `order` model that `belongs_to :user`, a `product` model, a join model `order_product`:

```
class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

The `order_product` model has a `quantity` column.

How can I find how many of a product `p` have been ordered by a user `u`? I would like to find a solution that uses rails 3's active record query syntax and takes place at the database level as much as possible please. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Good question, an example of this is sometimes difficult to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
u.order_products.where(:product_id => p.id).sum(:quantity)
```

That's a single SQL query, good for displaying one product. If you're displaying multiple products, then you would group by product ID, thereby giving you a Hash of values, from which you do your lookups.

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like below if you want to use Rails 3 query chain

p.order_product.includes("order").where(:orders => {:user_id => 'user_id'}).sum(:quantity)

Try to see if it works, maybe i miss out something